# Universe with another kind of particles

Tags: particle-physics, universe, physical-constants

Could we imagine a universe with particles having types and properties different from those which exist in our universe?

Comment: Sure! Go ahead and imagine it. You won't be the first person to do so. Make it as richly detailed as you like. Or make it simple, and study it or simulate it to see if rich detail "[emerges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence)." But, this question probably will be closed because it isn't a question about "mainstream physics" (i.e., it isn't about something that actual, working physicists study.)

Comment: Thank you. But if the question is closed, I could put it another way by integrating it into what physicists study. For example: are the types and properties of particles in our universe mandatory for a universe to exist.

Comment: I could also say: are the laws of physics absolutes which are imposed on any universe?

Answer (score 2):

People can and do imagine different universes. You see them in movies all the time. They often have little to do with physics. Or sometimes physics is used to make them more realistic. See https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

People also imagine universes where physics is different than our universe all the time to better study physics. For example, there are a number of constants that determine a lot of the universe's behavior. Imagine if the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) was a little different than it is. Stars would not form carbon atoms. Imagine if gravity was stronger. Stars would be smaller and burn out more quickly. Sometimes you learn some good questions to ask. Why does a universe that can support life appear to be possible only for a [very narrow range of physical constants](http://abyss.uoregon.edu/%7Ejs/21st_century_science/lectures/lec28.html)?

People also imagine simpler universes that are real, either because they are close to real and easier to figure out, or because we simply don't know the full set of laws and we do the best we can with what we know. Thus people use classical physics, even though it is an approximation to a world that is quantum mechanical and relativistic. People use the standard model even though [gravity is hard to fit into it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_beyond_the_Standard_Model).